# Hard Circle Geometry proofs

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles

I need help with this circle Geometry question, I got a and b but need help with c.

[image]

Comment: Please do **not** try to deface the question after it's solved.

Comment: Do not deface. This is a bad question, but removing the pic makes it awful, and we will not allow that. There is nothing to see in meta, that message was autogenerated by the site software in response to my choice of reason to lock. I locked this to stop the rollbacks.

Comment: Can soemone edit it and lock this thread?

Comment: You didn't get it! :-( :-( .-( You are .... OUTTA HERE. This is a rule, and my job is to enforce the rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(i) is easy and acts as a hint to the parts that follow.

(ii) $\angle GBF = \angle GCA$ (angles in the same segment)

$ \angle GCA = \angle HDF$ (for the same reason and is a result from (i))

$ \angle HDF = \angle HBF$ (for the same reason as above).

(iii) Both chords subtends equal angles (ie. $\angle BCG = \angle BAK$)

Added: If two chords of the same circle are respectively subtended by the same sized angle(s) on the circumference, these two chords must be equal in length.

Comment: can you expand on iii pls 
PS ii was alright, just need help with 3

Comment: @Ryuga800 See the added reasons.

Answer (score 1):

i. As $\angle BFH=\angle BDH=\frac{\pi}{2}$, $BFHD$ is cyclic with $(BH)$ being the diameter of the circumscribed circle. Similarly, as $\angle CFA=\angle CDA=\frac{\pi}{2}$, $AFDC$ is cyclic with $(AC)$ being the diameter of the circumscribed circle.

ii. $\angle GBF\equiv\underbrace{\angle GBA=\angle GCA}_{\bigcirc ABC}\equiv
\underbrace{\angle FCA=\angle FDA}_{\bigcirc AFDC}\equiv 
\underbrace{\angle FDH=\angle FBH}_{\bigcirc BFHD}$.

iii. $(BF)$ is both angle bisector and altitude of $\triangle GBH \Rightarrow$
$\triangle GBH$ - isosceles  $\Rightarrow BG= BH$. Similarly $\triangle KBH$ - isosceles $\Rightarrow BH=BK$.