# Altitudes in a Triangle Problem

Tags: geometry

Altitudes $\overline{AP}$ and $\overline{BQ}$ of an acute triangle $\triangle ABC$ intersect at point $H$. If $HP=5$ while $HQ=2$, then calculate $(BP)(PC)-(AQ)(QC)$.[image: Diagram]

When I first saw this problem, I immediately thought of similar triangles. However, I currently cannot find the solution with them.

Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the similarity of corresponding triangles:
$$\frac{HP}{BP}=\frac{HQ}{QA}=\frac{PC}{AP}=\frac{QC}{BQ}$$
follows:
$$BP\cdot PC-AQ\cdot QC =HP\cdot AP-HQ\cdot BQ\\
=HP(HP+HA)-HQ(HQ+HB)=HP^2-HQ^2=21,$$
where the identity $$PH\cdot HA=QH\cdot HB\tag{*}$$ 
was used.

The last identity can be aquired from the problem solved [elsewhere](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2690587/293846), where it was shown (in notation of the reference) that $HG=2HF$ and  $HK= 2 HD$. The identity (*) then follows from the well-known equality for the intersecting chords:
$$
AH\cdot HK=CH\cdot HG \Leftrightarrow AH\cdot 2 HD=CH\cdot 2 HF\Leftrightarrow AH\cdot HD=CH\cdot HF.
$$

Comment: Can you kindly explain how you concluded the triangles to be similar?

Comment: The similarity relations $BQC\sim BPH\sim HQA\sim CPA$ are very simple connecting right triangles with a common acute angle.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:   since $ABPQ$ is cyclic, it follows from the [power of a point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_point) that:

$$CP \cdot CB = CQ \cdot CA \;\;\iff\;\; CP \cdot (CP+PB) = CQ \cdot (CQ+QA)$$

Using that triangles $\triangle HPC, \triangle HCQ$ are right, it then follows that:

$$\require{cancel}
CP \cdot PB - CQ \cdot QA = CQ^2 - CP^2= (\cancel{CH^2}-HQ^2)-(\cancel{CH^2}-HP^2) = \ldots
$$